# How to traverse dom tree on jquery chosen change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using jQuery chosen for my selects and I need to do alter some fields on change. Here'es my change code which works:

```
j(".address").chosen().change(function(evt, value) {
    console.log(evt);
    address_id = value.selected;
});
```

If I log the evt variable to the console I can see it has a property called currentTarget which appears to point to the original select element which has been hidden. If I do the following:

```
evt.currentTarget.remove();
```

This removes the select from the DOM as I would expect so that shows that the object does relate to the select box. So if I try to traverse the DOM instead using that object as a starting point I just get errors. For example if I do the following:

```
evt.currentTarget.parents('.form-group').remove();
```

It just errors with the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Ideally I want to do something like this:

```
evt.currentTarget.parents('.form-group').next('.form-group').find('.address').val("some data")
```

Please don't suggest just using ID's as that's not going to work for what I am trying to build I want a generic solution that will work with classes even if there are multiple instances on the same page.

Comment: You can't traverse from a non existing element. You are removing `currentTarget` how would it be defined after that. If you must remove it do so after you are done using it.

Comment: Sorry I think you've misunderstood, I'm not actually removing it I was just using that as an example to say that using the remove() function works so the object obviously relates to the right element.

Comment: ah it makes a lot more sense then :)

Comment: But I think `evt.currentTarget` is not a jQuery object but a node object which also have `remove` method but wouldn't have `parents` as it's jQuery only. Try `$(evt.currentTarget)` instead.

Comment: Yeah that works thanks a lot :-) I can accept your answer in 4 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evt.currentTarget` is a node which doesn't have the same API as a jQuery element but does have a `remove` method.

Wrap it up in jQuery like so `j(evt.currentTarget)` as jQuery seems to be `j` in your case.